# Custom RecyclerView Rendering Issue

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to make custom bouncy RecyclerView so I hacked some code...

```
package ...;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;

public class BounceRecyclerView extends RecyclerView {
    private static final int MAX_Y_OVERSCROLL_DISTANCE = 200;

    private Context mContext;
    private int mMaxYOverscrollDistance;

    BounceRecyclerView(Context context){
        super(context);
        mContext = context;
        initBounceRecyclerView();
    }

    BounceRecyclerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
        super(context, attrs);
        mContext = context;
        initBounceRecyclerView();
    }

    BounceRecyclerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle){
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        mContext = context;
        initBounceRecyclerView();
    }

    private void initBounceRecyclerView()
    {
        //get the density of the screen and do some maths with it on the max overscroll distance
        //variable so that you get similar behaviors no matter what the screen size

        final DisplayMetrics metrics = mContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        final float density = metrics.density;

        mMaxYOverscrollDistance = (int) (density * MAX_Y_OVERSCROLL_DISTANCE * 0.25);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean overScrollBy(int deltaX, int deltaY, int scrollX, int scrollY,
                                   int scrollRangeX, int scrollRangeY, int maxOverScrollX,
                                   int maxOverScrollY, boolean isTouchEvent)
    {
        //This is where the magic happens, we have replaced the incoming maxOverScrollY with
        // our own custom variable mMaxYOverscrollDistance;
        return super.overScrollBy(deltaX, deltaY, scrollX, scrollY, scrollRangeX, scrollRangeY,
                maxOverScrollX, mMaxYOverscrollDistance, isTouchEvent);
    }
}
```

and when I try to use this class in my layout file I got this error:

```
The following classes could not be instantiated:
- ....BounceRecyclerView (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
 Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code or show sample data when shown in the IDE
```

And this is main part of stack:

```
Exception Details java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: ....BounceRecyclerView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet)
```

It seems to me like constructor with (android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) parameters can't be found, but as you can see it exists...

Also when I open BounceRecyclerView.java in Android Studio constructors are gray and curvy underlined which indicates that they aren't being used.

Comment: *but as you can see it exists* .... but is not public ...

Comment: By changing BounceRecyclerView(...) to public BounceRecyclerView(...) it worked...

Comment: Build -> Rebuild Project  -- try to rebuild project